# Excel 2010: How to delete rows that contain blank data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with 15 columns and about 16,000 rows of data. The first five columns show revenue for the past five years, the remaining columns contain account contact information. I only need to keep accounts that have had some kind of revenue within the last five years; the rest I can delete. I'm trying to find a way to easily identify or group the rows that have all five revenue columns empty. Is there a filter I can apply? A sorting method? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use the generic filters?   Data > sort & filter > filter

Answer (score 0):

Think you just want something like the following.

1)  Create a column against each row with this formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(Year1),ISBLANK(Year2),ISBLANK(Year3),ISBLANK(Year4),ISBLANK(Year5)),"DELETE","")
```

Obviously, if your data actually has zeros then the formula would need to be different

2)  Filter to this on "DELETE" and then choose to delete rows - will only delete the ones in view